# Dérivative and square condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need help concerning the following problem : 
Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow R$ a differentiable function with: $f(a+)=+\infty$ ,$ f(b-)=-\infty$ and $f'(x)+f^{2}(x)\geq -1$. Prove that $b-a\geq \pi$ and find an example when $b-a=\pi $ .
the only think I noticed is that if we let $g=f'+f^{2}+1$ we have that $f$ is a solution of the differential equation 
$y'+y^{2}=g$ , I thought that finding the general expression of this differential equation would help express $f$ in a more efficient way so that we can make the $\pi$ appear , but I am stuck on solving the differential equation . Is there any way to solve it ? thank you .

Comment: Maybe you could rewrite the inequality as  $$\frac{f'}{1+f^2}\geq-1
$$ and integrate it?

Comment: oh yeah , why I didn't notice that , it was easy in fact , thank you